# Determining type of isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I have to determine whether the singularities of a function are poles, essential or removable. The function I have to work with is $z/(z^2-1)^2$. My question is if in order to answer this question, do I necessarily need to find the Laurent expansion of this expression or if there is any theorem I could use to make this easier.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A quotient of polynomials has only poles or removable singularities. The latter are rather easy to check. What are the roots of the denominator?

Comment: Ok, I see. But how do you know that the quotient of polynomials has only poles or removable singularities?

Comment: [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).